# JDBC Update failing for larger volume Collections?

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, collections

The below code snippet is failing with the underlying exception for Map Size
of the order for 30K+

How can I get this done without violating the limit of cursors ?.

```
orclSQLDevDB=DBConnector.getOracleDevDB();

            for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : issueMapMSRB2.entrySet()) {

                orclSQLDevDB.setAutoCommit(false);

                PreparedStatement psORACLE = orclSQLDevDB
                        .prepareStatement(NamedQueries.oracle_INSERT);
                psORACLE.setString(1, entry.getKey());
                psORACLE.setString(2, "NMDF");
                if (issueMapMSRB2.get(entry.getKey()).contains("_O_"))
                    psORACLE.setString(3, "ORACLE");
                else
                    psORACLE.setString(3, "MSSQL");
                psORACLE.setString(4, issueMapMSRB2.get(entry.getKey()));



                psORACLE.executeUpdate();  // FAILURE LINE.
                orclSQLDevDB.commit();

            }
```

Exception stack trace

```
16 Jan 2015 14:52:26,540 [main] ERROR  RunAnalytics: [Oracle Dev DB]-ORA-01000: maximum open cursors exceeded

java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01000: maximum open cursors exceeded

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:440)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:396)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:837)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:445)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:191)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:523)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:207)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForRows(T4CPreparedStatement.java:1010)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1315)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3576)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeUpdate(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3657)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.executeUpdate(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1350)
    at com.citi.Analytics.RunAnalytics.dumpResultToOracle(RunAnalytics.java:218)
    at com.citi.Analytics.RunAnalytics.main(RunAnalytics.java:125)
```

Comment: You don't need to define the PreparedStatement in the loop. Bring it out of the loop and the `setAutoCommit` then try again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to define the PreparedStatement in the loop. Bring it out of the loop and the setAutoCommit then try again. You need to also make sure to close out the PreparedStatement. You should use a `try-catch-finally` and close it in the `finally`.

Here is a great example from Oracle: [Using Prepared Statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html)

Comment: I would also add in what @fvaleri mentioned

Answer (score 2):

Close statements and never prepare inside loops.

Answer (score 1):

You need to close your `'Connection'` when your done using it, that's why you getting to many cursors open which haven't been closed before.

Comment: I am not done using the connection here it fails and i am closing the connection in a finally block.
I cannot open 30K connections and close them for each update

Comment: so maybe you need to consider make those updates by some kilobyte limit. 
measure each update size or try to see at which limit everything goes wrong

Comment: the Prepare statement needed to be  moved out of the for loop that did the trick